# Divisor value in for loop is mysteriously (?) changing

Tags: java, for-loop, integer-division

So I have been at this for hours, and I'm honestly completely stuck. I've wrote a for loop that counts the amount of numbers in an integer, but I've found that the divisor value changes once i enter a number above 10 digits, and I can't figure out why. I've searched the internet to no avail, so I would appreciate any help or tips if you have any. Thank you!

```
 public static int getNumberOfDigits(long creditCardNumber)
{
    //problem with 0's at beginning and more than 10 digits
    int nDigitsInCard = 0;
    int divisor = (int) creditCardNumber;
    for(int i = 0; i <= creditCardNumber; i++){
        while(divisor!=0){
            divisor/=10;
            ++nDigitsInCard;
        }
}
    // return the number of digits in nDigitsInCard

    return nDigitsInCard;
}
```

Comment: change int to long. You are dealing with too big of numbers for the int primitive to handle. What happens is it loops back around again (sat the range was from - 10 to 10) then putting in 11 would loop back around to -10.

Comment: Prior to writing the ```(int)``` cast in the initialization of ```divisor```, there was presumably a compiler warning about possible loss of significant digits. Adding a cast suppresses the warning but does not solve the underlying problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int`s can't hold numbers greater than 2,147,483,647. You need to stick to `long`s to work with larger numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, after changing the data type to long, my code is still having the same problem.

Comment: @DarianRay Please update your question with the new code.

Comment: Nevermind, I've figured it out, I've been using the wrong variable. The long data type was a part of it though. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Integers can only hold numbers up to 2 ^ 32 - 1. Also, why are you casting the input parameter to an integer?

Another thing is that you are counting the number of digits in every number leading up to divisor since you are looping from 0 all the way up to `creditCardNumber` in the `for(int i = 0; i <= creditCardNumber; i++){ ... }`. So for example 10000 would return the number of digits in 1, the number of digits in 2, all the way up to 10000.

Lastly, the whole function can be done in one line with

```
return Long.toString(creditCardNumber).length();
```

or

```
return creditCardNumber.toString().length();
```

if you change `creditCardNumber` to a `Long` instead of a `long`, but you would have to call it with an `l` suffix at the end.

If you want something even shorter, you can do

```
return (creditCardNumber+"").length();
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat nice catch, fixed

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the input, and I've since fixed all of those errors. I would have used the .length shortcut if I could have, but my professor stated explicitly not to, so I used a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you have the number greater than 10 digits, the conversion to an integer doesn't complete because the integer can't hold valures greater than 2^31 - 1, or 2,147,483,647, which is a number with only 10 digits. I recommend sticking with `long`.